# Natural way to run a JS function only once when a page is opened for the first time, regardless of refreshes

Tags: jsf

Is there any natural way to make a JavaScript function run only once on JSF page?

I have a JSF page with ViewScoped backing bean. I want to run a JS function when the page is loading first time and do not do so if a user refreshes the page. Is it possible to do so without adding variables into user's session, etc?

Comment: If the enduser refreshes the page, then the JSF view scope is basically also terminated and restarted. So the question title is rather confusing.

Comment: pick one `$(window).load(function() { alert("ready"); });` or `$(document).ready(function() { alert("load"); });`

Comment: @Daniel: this is re-executed when the page is refreshed. That is, when the definition of "refresh" in the question is indeed exactly the effect of pressing F5 / Ctrl+R in webbrowser.

Comment: @BalusC Could you please suggest an improvement for the title, so it describes the problem clearer? I can't come up with the better unfortunately. I'm not a native English speaker. Thanks

Comment: Your concrete question is still somewhat ambiguous, but I think that the current title correctly represents what you're really asking? The only missing piece of information is: how about opening the same page in a new browser window/tab/session?

Comment: I think the only way would be to have a SessionBean with a function that is called every time and it is initialized to true at construct and set to false at every read. You could use this function to return the value and render or not some javascript code?

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie that is somewhat I'm doing right now. I'm just wondering if there any better way

Comment: @BalusC thank you for helping with the title. Actually I do not care about the application behaviour in case a user wants to open a new tab, window or start a new session. However I do not think I have any other option but keeping a value in a DB(or any storage) to implement this behaviour in case of starting new session. If it was a requirement I would know exactly what to do.

Comment: You can try using javascript session variables http://www.sitepoint.com/cookieless-javascript-session-variables/ but I think serverside bean would be a more "by the book" solution!

Answer (score 0):

set a html cookie on the page load and check if it is set on the next refresh, run js if it was not set.

Comment: This basically duplicates what the HTTP session facility already provides.